# GPRS and Weather Shield

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I have GPRS(GPRS_Shield_V1.0), weather shield and arduino uno R3. When I use Arduino and GPRS it works perfectly and when I used Weather Shield it also worked perfectly. But weather shield needs wire library, to use sensors. And when I use GPRS library with wire library, my program prints the same string many times. How I can use these two shields together?

These are some pics of my connected shields:

http://puu.sh/gcvk3/85595c38c7.jpg

http://puu.sh/gcvpc/22185212d3.jpg

As you can see, I'm not using A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 pins for GPRS Shield. Thank you!

Comment: The Arduino StackExchange is probably a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The GPRS shield should use serial communication with AT commands, and thats it. 
I can't see any problems with your configuration, make sure that you dont use the same pins for the weather station.
A good test would be to use jumper to connect each shield or look at the scheme of each shield.